# LdapSearch not showing traffic in wireshark

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to set up LDAP and would like to monitor traffic using wireshark. Using [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html), I can run the ldapsearch command as it instructs, but it's not showing any traffic in Wireshark (even when running on all interfaces). Am I missing a conceptual keystone about how LDAP is supposed to function right now? Shouldn't I be seeing some type of traffic on the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem. For some reason, dpkg did not run the auto-configure script when installing slapd, causing the first `ldapsearch` command in that tutorial to run, but not the second. Turns out that first `ldapsearch` command actually doesn't send network traffic (though I'm not sure why/which flag dictates that).

Running `dpkg-reconfigure slapd` and executing the `ldapsearch -x` results in LDAP traffic on the wire.